# Efficient Scientific Notation

Tags: code-golf, string, math

The other day my chemistry teacher was explaining to us about [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) (using a small number and multiplying it by powers of ten to express large numbers more easily), which brought me back a few years to when I first learnt it. After learning the basics, we had done a bunch of typical maths questions, some of which were like the following:

> Represent the following in scientific notation:
>   a) 50000000
>   b) 120000000000000
>   c) 90000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   d) pi^e^i^j^k^std::vector
>   ...
>   z) **200**
>   ...

And I thought, "What? We were told that scientific notation was used to make writing large numbers more efficient, but some cases aren't more efficient at all!"

Consider the number

```
300
```

and its representation in scientific notation:

```
3x10^2
```

What, the scientifically notated version actually takes up more space? We can't have that now can we? (Screen space is precious.)
We could determine ourselves if it's more space efficient to write a number in scientific notation or not, or...

## Task

Your program or function should take as input a single positive number `n` of arbitrary size (up to what your language supports) and output the scientifically notated version of the number.
However, if the original number `n`, after removal of trailing zeroes and trailing decimal place, takes less or the same amount of characters to display than its scientifically notated version, you must output that original number `n` instead.

Your code needs to be as short as possible because the output also has to be as short as possible.

## Specifications

Efficient Scientific Notation is defined as follows:

```
bx10^e
```

`b` is the input number appropriately divided by powers of 10 such that `1 <= b < 10`.  This number must have all trailing zeroes (and decimal point if required) removed, but must have the precision of the original number (up to the decimal point limit in your language, of course). Ie `90000` becomes `9`, `13.500` becomes `1.35`, `0.000675` becomes `6.75` etc. If this number ends up containing more decimal places than your language can handle, it should be rounded to that maximum number of decimal places.

`e` is the exponent to which ten is raised such that `n = b x 10^e` (remember that this number needs to be negative if `n` is smaller than 1). This number should not have any trailing zeros or a decimal place (mainly because if it's not an integer something is wrong...).

The characters `x10^` *must* remain as is in the string between `b` and `e`.

## Test cases

```
Input -> output
1 -> 1
20 -> 20
3000000 -> 3x10^6
400000 -> 400000
0.008093 -> 0.008093
0.007835000000000 -> 0.007835
0.000003000000 -> 3x10^-6
0.00000065 -> 6.5x10^-7
0 -> 0
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

## Other rules and clarification

- Trailing zeros (and/or trailing decimal place) are not counted towards the character count of the original input number `n`. Keep that in mind for cases such as test case 6
- You may assume that if the input number is less than 1, it will always start with a 0 in place for the ones digit (as in test cases 5-8).
- Input number will never be negative
- Built-ins that make this challenge trivial and standard loopholes are disallowed
- A trailing newline in the output is OK

**EDIT**
Thanks to user81655 for pointing out test cases 7 and 8 had incorrect powers of ten. I have now fixed those so make sure your code evaluates them correctly.

Comment: So, uh, should I ask what the output for input `pi^e^i^j^k^std::vector` would be?

Comment: @Geobits Hmm, well if you can assign a numerical value to std::vector then maybe... No, only numbers will be present in the input (except a decimal place for floating point input).

Comment: This would be far easier *and* we would take up less of your "precious screen space" if it  used `e`: `9000 -> 9e3` (almost **over 9,000**!)

Comment: @Cyoce I thought about that, but I really based this challenge on the way it is generally written (as in physically written), which seems to be with `x10^`. And it would be a fair bit of rework on the question, which I don't think is that appropriate now that it's posted

Comment: @indeed please note that in scientific notation, trailing zeroes DO count after the decimal place.... so while "0.4" = "4*10^-1", "0.40" = "4.0*10^-1"

this distinction is kind of important

Comment: also, this creates the distinction that 40 = 4*10^1 and 40. = 4.0*10^1

Comment: @sig_seg_v I (sort of) understand what you are saying, but I thought I had defined a pretty solid explanation of how scientific notation will work with this challenge - OK it turned out to not be *exactly* like it should be. (ugh I thought all this would get sorted in the Sandbox...)

Comment: @indeed it's not that your definition in the challenge isn't clear, it just rubs me the wrong way as a mathematician/scientist that, in this problem, 40.0 = 40 = 4*10^1... pay me no mind if you don't want to adopt my suggested change ;), it's just that there is no such thing as a "trailing decimal place" in scientific notation.......

Comment: @sig_seg_v So you are suggesting that `b` under Specifications should contain the same amount of digits after the decimal place as the input? I'm just trying to figure out how I can implement your suggestion but still make it clear what is going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35376/discussion-between-sig-seg-v-and-indeed).

Comment: `0.008093 -> 0.008098` I think you has a typo.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks, fixed now

Comment: Why would a chemistry teacher be the first one to teach students scientific notation?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code She wasn't, hence "brought me back a few years to when I first learnt it [in maths class]"

Comment: BF: `,[.,]`, although it's [Abusing native number types to trivialize a problem](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8245/61384).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ES6, <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```
x=>(e=s=>s.replace(/e\+?/,'x10^'),z=e(x.toExponential()),y=e(''+x))[z.length]?z:y
```

Probably fails for some edge cases where `toString` insists on exponential format.

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @user81655.

Comment: Nice idea. By the way, it looks like you forgot the `/` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Also you could rearrange this slightly to save 2 bytes: `x=>(e=s=>s.replace(/e\+?/,'x10^'),z=e(x.toExponential()),y=e(''+x))[z.length]?z:y`

Comment: @user81655 Ah, what happened there is that my browser confused me by wrapping the long line in such a way as I thought that a new line had crept in there by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <strike>346</strike> <strike>342</strike> <strike>319</strike> 302 bytes

```
L=len;N=str(float(input()))
if N.endswith('.0'):N=N[:-2]
if'e'in N:C,P=N.split('e');N=N.replace('e','x10^')
else:
 C=N.strip('.0').replace('.','');F=N.find('.')
 if L(C)>1:C=C[0]+'.'+C[1:]
 P=((L(N) if F==-1 else F)-1-N.lstrip('0').find(C[0]))
print(min([N,'{0}x10^{1}'.format(C,int(P))],key=L))
```

Probably horribly golfed, but hey, this is my first try at something like this. It's hard to read, so it must be good.

As far as I'm aware, it should work on every case, even with Python's tendency to automatically convert numbers past whatever threshold into scientific notation (except with that cool and fancy 'e'). I don't remember exactly how I made that be able to return standard form numbers, but it does that.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6, <s>96</s> 90 bytes

I feel like this could be shorter, but this is my best for now

```perl6
{my \s=($_,*×(1>$_??10!!.1)…10>*>=1);min(s[*-1]~"x10^"~(1>$_??1-s!!s-1),$_,by=>&chars)}
```

**usage**: Assign this to a variable

Here it is ungolfed a bit with some bad commentary:

```perl6
my &f = -> $n {
    my $a = 1 > $n ?? 10 !! .1;             # If $n < 1, we will multiply by 10
                                            # in the sequence below, else by 0.1

    my @seq = ($n, * × $a ... 10 > * >= 1); # Sequence starting at $n, 
                                            # multiply the previous value by $a
                                            # until we reach a number 1 <= x < 10

    # Join the last element in @seq, "x10^", and the length of @seq,
    # with an extra subtraction for numbers less than 1.
    # this gets us our scientific notation.
    my $science = @seq[*-1] ~ "x10^" ~ @seq - (1 > $n ?? @seq*2 !! 1); 

    min($science, $n, by => &chars) # Uses the &chars function to
                                    # choose a min value and return it.
}
```

Comment: Swap `$_ <1` with `1>$_` and `1 <=* <10` with `10>*>=1`

Comment: I actually meant to do that last night but I forgot. I'll update it when I get home

Answer (score 2):

### TI BASIC (nspire): 112 bytes

```
Define f(x)=
Prgm
string(x)➝a
If x≥1 Then
format(x,"s")➝a
EndIf
instring(a,"ᴇ")➝b
left(a,b-1)&"x10^"&mid(a,b+1)➝a
If dim(a)<dim(string(n)) or x<1 Then
Disp a
Else
Disp x
Endif
EndPrgm
```

**Explanation**

```
If x≥1 Then
format(x,"s")➝a
EndIf
```

Converts the input to scientific notation with the format function if it already isn't in that format- as small decimals are automatically converted.

```
instring(a,"ᴇ")➝b
left(a,b-1)&"x10^"&mid(a,b+1)➝a
```

Finds the position of the fancy E that denotates exponents and replaces it with "x10^".

```
If dim(a)<dim(string(x)) or x<1 Then
Disp a
Else
Disp x
Endif
```

Checks which output is larger and returns the optimal one. Unless it is a small decimal, which are smaller by default.

Answer (score 0):

### Python (3.5) 177 bytes

A solution using regular expression

```
import re
g=lambda s:re.sub(r"e\+?(-?)0?","x10^\\1",s)
def f(i):
 t=g(re.sub(r"\.[0]*e","e","%e"%i))
 u=g(re.sub(r"(\..*)[0]*$","\\1",str(i)))
 return t if len(u)>len(t) else u
```

### Explanation

Importation of regexp module

```
import re
```

Définition of the lambda function to replace `e` by `x10^`

```
g=lambda s:re.sub("e\+?(-?)0?","x10^\\1",s)
def f(i):
```

Convertion of the string in scientific notation

```
 t=g(re.sub(r"\.[0]*e","e","%e"%i))
```

Remove 0 padding in the orginal string

```
 u=g(re.sub(r"(\..*)[0]*$","\\1",str(i)))
```

compare length

```
 return t if len(u)>len(t) else u
```

### Results

```
>>> [f(i) for i in [1, 20, 3000000, 400000, 0.008093, 0.007835000000000, 0.000003000000, 0.00000065, 0]]
['1', '20', '3x10^6', '400000', '0.008093', '0.007835', '3x10^-6', '6.5x10^-7', '0']
```